# Wildfly TimerService unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, java-ee-7

I'm having some trouble configuring a timer in java. To be precise - I'm receiving the following error when trying to deploy my `peripherial.war`.

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"peripherial.war\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"peripherial.war\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type TimerService with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public io.github.tastypenguinbacon.peripherial.heartbeat.service.PassiveHeartbeatService(Cache, TimerService)
  at io.github.tastypenguinbacon.peripherial.heartbeat.service.PassiveHeartbeatService.<init>(PassiveHeartbeatService.java:0)
"},"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"peripherial.war\".WeldStartService"]}
```

The `standalone.xml` file seems to be fine. The part (at least I'm expecting it to be) responsible for configuring the timer service seems also fine:

```
<timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
  <data-stores>
    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
  </data-stores>
</timer-service>
```

I'm instantiating the TimerService through the `@Inject`, using constructor based injection if it's somehow relevant. 
I'm using `wildfly-11.0.0.Alpha`. The  only thing changed in the default `standalone.xml` file is the IP addresses which are able to access the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TimerService` is a JEE application server resource. It is not automatically available to CDI to be `@Inject`-ed. The way to obtain it (ref e.g. the [JEE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)) is:

```
@Resource
TimerService timerService;
```

This might suit your purposes; if you really want it exposed as a CDI bean, it is fortunately trivial. Just make the `@Resource` field a producer too - you can have a separate class for that:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class TimerServiceProducer {
    @Resource
    @Produces
    TimerService timerService;
}
```

I'm not sure if `@ApplicationScoped` is absolutely necessary, but it won't hurt either.